# Using native sql in Native SQL Hibernate

Tags: hibernate

I have a complex sql i was planning to integrate  and was going the integrateing with hibernate through named query now please advise can I write my native sql  in hbm.xml file inside ..

```
<![CDATA[  ] tag and in my pojos 
I will retrieve like  session.getNamedQuery ,
```

please advise for native sql this approach is the best one ..!! I want to keep the query in xml

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you do in xml file:

```
<!-- stock.hbm.xml -->
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.mkyong.common.Stock" table="stock" ...>
        <id name="stockId" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="STOCK_ID" />
            <generator class="identity" />
        </id>
        <property name="stockCode" type="string">
            <column name="STOCK_CODE" length="10" not-null="true" unique="true" />
        </property>
        ...
    </class>

   <sql-query name="findStockByStockCodeNativeSQL">
  <return alias="stock" class="com.mkyong.common.Stock"/>
  <![CDATA[select * from stock s where s.stock_code = :stockCode]]>
  </sql-query>

</hibernate-mapping>
```

Using this query

```
Query query = session.getNamedQuery("findStockByStockCodeNativeSQL")
.setString("stockCode", "7277");
```

Read from [here](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-named-query-examples/)

Comment: But this is not a SQL, that is a HQL.

Comment: @Vash, How is that now?

Comment: @elbek so HQL is still used. ,i WAS LOOKING FOR SQL

Comment: `<![CDATA[select * from stock s where s.stock_code = :stockCode]]>` is not hql, it is sql. that is why it is inside `sql-query` tag